# Issue passing PHP session variables

Tags: php, session

I am trying to pass PHP session variables from page to page. I am receiving an undefined index error. I am using PHP 8.12 on apache 2.48 on localhost.

I have tried with a couple of very simple code snippets, and I am getting the same error, for example:

`page1.php`:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["name"]="xxx";
    header ("location:page2.php");
    exit;
?>
```

If I `echo $_SESSION["name"]` on `page1.php`, the correct value is displayed.

`page2.php`:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION["name"];
?>
```

On page 2 I am receiving an undefined index "name" error.

I have a feeling there maybe something I am missing in the php.ini file as I can't see any reason why such simple code should be failing.

Comment: `session_start()` returns a boolean value. Be sure it's not `false`.

Comment: Make sure you have not disabled session . See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356373/how-to-disable-session-in-php)

Comment: A few randoms ideas: 1) Your browser doesn't store cookies; 2) you edit a wrong file; 3) you doesn't save your file changes; 4) you made a typo in your `$_SESSION` variable; 5) your server is misconfigured and wipes session files or can't write files (check your `session_save_path()`); 5) your HDD/SSD is full // Also, your `Location` word needs a capital `L` char and you need a space after the `:` char.

Comment: 6) check the path of the session cookies in your browser if page 2 is in a different dir. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9885543/1685196).

Comment: But seriously, fix your header syntax first and try again. Here's your brother that made same typos in HTTP headers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6777970/1597430

Comment: 7) you mix HTTP/HTTPS; 8) you set `session.cookie_secure = On`, but use HTTP; 9) the code you show us here is not the code you actually use; 10) you set invalid cookies - check you browser's Console output, all cookie policy violation warnings should be there; 11) you have `.htaccess` in the same dir or global Apache settings that mess with your cookies.

Comment: I have checked through the 11 points to no avail... as an fyi there is no need for location in the header to be Location and there is no need for a space after the : the page redirects without issue, changing header() as suggested makes no difference the $_SESSION variables still don't get passed

Comment: Check dev tools and inspect the cookie. When does it expire? does it change value between 2 pages? does it exist?

Comment: It works for me.  Are you sure that the files you posted are what you are using ?  It looks like your Sessions are disabled.  Have a look at the answer here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42596339/php-session-disabled-with-enabled-session-support